# Write list of dictionaries to separate lines in S3 file

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using Kinesis Firehose to read data from Kinesis Stream and store in s3 json files, every string is written into separate lines:

```json
{"DeviceID":"1000000","DeviceTypeID":2,"DeviceRecordTime":"2020-11-10"}
{"DeviceID":"1000000","DeviceTypeID":2,"DeviceRecordTime":"2020-11-10"}
```

I tried to read data from Kinesis Stream with Lambda and boto3, put all records into single list and write it to s3 with put_object function, that's why I get:

```json
{"_1":[{"DeviceID":"1000000","DeviceTypeID":2,"DeviceRecordTime":"2020-11-10"},{"DeviceID":"1000000","DeviceTypeID":2,"DeviceRecordTime":"2020-11-10"}]}
```

Is there any way to achieve the same output with Lambda as Kinesis Firehose does, separate json strings in separate lines?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: If your code is calling PutObject then you have complete control over what's written, no?

Comment: jarmod, that's the problem, I don't know how to control it and achieve what I want. Not sure if it's possible at all.